# Can not link Azure Function App to Static Web App, error "Cannot link backend with a preexisting Azure Static Web Apps configuration."

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

I am following this [turorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own) and trying to link Function App to Static Web App. But I keep getting "Cannot link backend with a preexisting Azure Static Web Apps configuration."
.

However, I could link this Function App to another test Static Web App. And those two Static Web Apps are identical, well atleast I am pretty sure they are identical.

- When creating a Static Web app deploy routine I left api location empty - `api_location: ""`.
- Static Web App is using Standart plan (not free).

[image]

**EDIT**

Adding Static Web App JSON view.

[image]

Comment: Verify the regions of both the static web app and the function app where those apps were hosted. There may be a conflict over region-level access. Provide those details; it could help to replicate the issue.

Comment: Static Web App is on West Europe, and Function App is on North region. The test web app is also on West Europe, and seems to work fine

Comment: My view is that this issue may be supposed to happen in two scenarios.

1. Under Static WebApp settings -> configuration -> lock may exist; if any, please delete that lock and try to add the API Functions

2. There is an API version mismatch between those two static web apps.

Comment: There is no locks - neither on Static Web App, not Function App. But how do I see what API version is for statics webb apps?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding documentation:

"*If a backend was previously linked to another static Web App, the auth configuration must first be removed from the backend before linking to a different Static Web App*"

Check az staticwebapp backends validate:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/backends?view=azure-cli-latest

If you link your Static Web App (swa) with a backend and then remove the swa do not forget to go to "Settings" and remove "Authorization" from your backend (this setting was created automatically when you linked the swa but not removed when you delete it)

Comment: This is very annoying. The only way I'm able to send telemetry from a Static Web App to an App Insights instance is by linking the Static Web App to a backend. This limitation prevents me from sending telemetry from two Static Web Apps that use the same backend. Any idea how to overcome my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue may cause because of Read-only Lock under configuration setting

1. Created a new Static WebApp on West Europe Region
   [image]
2. If any lock exists on Static Web Apps should not allow to add any backend APIs
   [image]
3. Link new Backend APIs as Function App with Lock
   [image]
4. After Removal of lock, Static Web Apps will allow to link new Backend
   [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

API Version check :
[image]